# Python package installation issues: discrepancy between installation check on terminal (Anaconda Prompt) and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, jupyter, pytorch

I have to install the Paysage package. I downloaded the GitHub repo and moved in it to launch the installation command.

Beforehand, I had Python 3.5.2 installed on my system (Windows10) with some packages such as NumPy, SciPy, Pandas, Matplotlib and others, and Jupyter notebook. The package documentation recommends to set up Paysage within an Anaconda environment, so I thought neat to install Anaconda3. This latter installed on my system Python 3.7.2. So now I have Python 3.7.2 under `conda` and Python 3.5.2 if for example I check the version with the `cmd` command `python --version`.

I think I have been too loose about it because now I could set up Paysage (apparently) properly, by having created an environment, moved to the Paysage folder where the `setup.py` lays, and did

```
pip install .
```

After a trial-error route, to gather all what needed in order to install the package, I finally succeeded. In fact, as I check whether Paysage is available, by running the script

```
try:
    import paysage
except ImportError:
    available = False
    print('Paysage not available')
else:
    available = True
    print('Paysage available')
```

it turns out that Paysage is indeed installed. As the script is executed, a message confirms it is ok:

```
(paysageTest) C:\Users\...>python test.py
Running paysage with the pytorch backend on the cpu
```

But the problem rises in the moment in which I try to do the same in a Jupyter Notebook. I have some guidelines and examples on notebooks and I would like to use them. If I type the same code as above in a Jupyter Notebook cell, it turns out that Paysage is unknown to the kernel running. So it seems that even if Paysage is installed, it can not be run by the notebook.

It is maybe due to the discrepancy between the Python installed version on the system and the one installed within the Anaconda? (The Jupyter notebook has been launched from an Anaconda Prompt, created for the Paysage setup purpose, as in the docs). It is maybe due to the fact that launching a notebook, even if from the Anaconda Prompt, that notebook relies on the Python version installed on the computer and thus version incompatibilities are lurking?

Comment: Fastest solution : install jupyter in your conda environment, then it will use a python kernel from this environment.
If you are to use Anaconda, you should likely drop your system Python.

Comment: The problem is that jupyter is indeed installed under conda (I think that Anaconda by default installs, among others, Jupyter notebook), both on `(base)` environment and on my brand new `(paysageTest)` one. But I can not understand which one, whether the one that came with Anaconda or the formerly installed version. Is there a way to check and eventually switch? Alternatively, could it be an option to uninstall everything and keeping only Anaconda and what is related to it?

Comment: `where jupyter` should tell you which one is active (system install or anaconda). If you install the conda package [`nb_conda_kernels`](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels) you shuold be able to select your environment `PaysageTest` from within jupyter, as long as you installed `ipykernel` in there.